# If we know $ u=f(x,y,z,t),g(y,z,t)=0,h(z,t)=0$, how to calculate the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have tried to calculate the partial derivative about x,y,z,t. However it is too complex.

Implicit function may be a wise idea, but I don't know how to use it because this may refer to composite funtion.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you **mean** by $\partial u/\partial y$ to begin with. Normally you would hold $x$, $z$ and $t$ constant while you vary $y$, but you can't do that because of the constraint $g(y,z,t)=0$. Could you try to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end  only $x$ and $y$  are independent variables. The variables $z$ and $t$ are linked to $y$ by the two equations
$$g(y,z,t)=0,\qquad h(z,t)=0\ .\tag{1}$$
These two equations implicitly define functions $y\mapsto z=\phi(y)$ and $y\mapsto t=\psi(y)$. We then have
$$u=f\bigl(x,y,\phi(y),\psi(y)\bigr)\ .$$
The outermost function $f$ has $4$ variable entries, denoted by $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ in the original definition of $u$. Since these variables are no longer all independent I shall write $f_{.i}$ for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i^{\rm th}$ entry. Concerning the remaining independent variables $x$ and $y$ one then has, by the chain rule,
$${\partial u\over\partial y}=f_{.2}\bigl(x,y,\phi(y),\psi(y)\bigr)+f_{.3}\bigl(x,y,\phi(y),\psi(y)\bigr)\phi'(y)+f_{.4}\bigl(x,y,\phi(y),\psi(y)\bigr)\psi'(y)\ .\tag{2}$$
In order to find $\phi'(y)$ and $\psi'(y)$ we have to differentiate $(1)$, i.e.,
$$g\bigl(y,\phi(y),\psi(y)\bigr)=0,\qquad h\bigl(\phi(y),\psi(y)\bigr)=0$$
with respect to $y$, and obtain
$$g_{.1}+g_{.2}\phi'(y)+g_{.3}\psi'(y)=0,\qquad h_{.1}\phi'(y)+h_{.2}\psi'(y)=0\ .\tag{3}$$
Given a point $(x_0,y_0)$ one finds $z_0=\phi(y_0)$ and $t_0=\psi(y_0)$ using $(1)$. The values $f_{.j}(x_0,y_0,z_0,t_0)$, $g_{.j}(y_0,z_0,t_0)$, and $h_{.j}(z_0,t_0)$ are then determined, so that $(3)$ allows to compute the derivative values $\phi'(y_0)$ and $\psi'(y_0)$. Finally $(2)$ leads to the $${\partial u\over\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$$ we are after.